# X-13-ARIMA with statsmodels.tsa.x13

Tags: python, statsmodels, temporary-files

I'm trying to use statsmodels.tsa.x13 with my Python 3.6 (anaconda\spider). I`ve already installed x13as and write this code:

```
X13PATH= os.chdir("C:\\x13\WinX13\\x13as")
x13results = x13_arima_analysis(endog = mb["G"], x12path=X13PATH, outlier=True,print_stdout=True)
```

where `mb["G"]` is pandas.core.series.Series. So, the result is following:

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\x13.py:460: IOWarning: Failed to delete resource C:\Users\SERGEY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2iwvb0uo.spc 
  IOWarning)
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\x13.py:463: IOWarning: Failed to delete resource C:\Users\SERGEY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_h3vwxc9 
  IOWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-3-8e98768a4534>", line 2, in <module>     
  x13results = x13_arima_analysis(endog = mb["G"], x12path=X13PATH, outlier=True,print_stdout=True)

 File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\x13.py", line 434, in x13_arima_analysis     
  ftempin.write(spec)

 File "C:\Anaconda\lib\tempfile.py", line 483, in func_wrapper    
   return func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

What's the problem? I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass as a string. Change

```
X13PATH= os.chdir("C:\\x13\WinX13\\x13as")
```

to

```
X13PATH= "C:\\x13\WinX13\\x13as"
```

From the [statsmodels docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.x13.x13_arima_analysis.html): "x12path (str or None) – The path to x12 or x13 binary. If None, the program will attempt to find x13as or x12a on the PATH or by looking at X13PATH or X12PATH depending on the value of prefer_x13."

Comment: Now I have this one:   
`X13NotFoundError: x12a and x13as not found on path. Give the path, put them on PATH, or set the X12PATH or X13PATH environmental variable.`  
But x13as.exe contained exactly in abovementioned folder. What am I doing wrong?